# GLES 2.0 error with model normals (or something else)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard

Here is a project where I modify the Google CardBoard example:
https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/cardboard-java

(I basically cut off a bunch of stuff: I don't need 3D audio feedback, I don't generate cubes. I don't have a "floor" in my 3D model (a large surface below rendered as a mesh), but instead I have a surface ahead of me (I call it screen), where I render a png image as a texture. Thus the shaders (fragment and vertex) are also really simple.)

Unfortunately I did something wrong during the modification and I cannot figure out what it is.

If I uncomment line 289 (`GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(screenNormalParam);`) in the MainActivity (https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/cardboard-java/blob/master/CardboardSample/src/main/java/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/samples/treasurehunt/MainActivity.java#L289), the application crashes after startup:

```
01-16 20:17:40.325 9167-9305/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-16 20:17:40.355 9167-9305/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0xaf440088 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 8 
01-16 20:17:40.355 9167-9305/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-16 20:17:40.485 9167-9302/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt I/MainActivity: onSurfaceCreated
01-16 20:17:40.515 9167-9305/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt V/RenderScript: Application requested CPU execution
01-16 20:17:40.525 9167-9302/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glEnableVertexAttribArray:193>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
01-16 20:17:40.525 9167-9302/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/MainActivity: Screen program params: glError 1281
01-16 20:17:40.535 9167-9305/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt V/RenderScript: 0xa126c400 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
01-16 20:17:40.545 9167-9302/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 231450
                                                                                               Process: com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt, PID: 9167
                                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Screen program params: glError 1281
                                                                                                   at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.checkGLError(MainActivity.java:177)
                                                                                                   at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.onSurfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:292)
                                                                                                   at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl$RendererHelper.callOnSurfaceCreated(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:811)
                                                                                                   at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl$RendererHelper.onSurfaceCreated(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:832)
                                                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
                                                                                                   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

My main problem is that I don't really get any more detailed information on what is wrong, `glError 1281` is very broad. With trial and error I figured out that after commenting that Line 289 (mentioned above) the application starts and seems like functioning, but it floods LogCat with this (not good):

```
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glVertexAttribPointer:533>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt E/MainActivity: drawing screen: glError 1281
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: drawing screen: glError 1281
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.checkGLError(MainActivity.java:177)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.drawScreen(MainActivity.java:406)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt.MainActivity.onDrawEye(MainActivity.java:368)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl.nativeOnDrawFrame(Native Method)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl.access$3200(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:52)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.CardboardViewNativeImpl$RendererHelper.onDrawFrame(CardboardViewNativeImpl.java:741)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
01-16 16:38:57.984 30664-30723/com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.samples.treasurehunt W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

The call stacks just lead me to the `checkGLError`, which leads me to generic `glError 1281`. I'm new to OpenGL debugging, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my simple shaders I didn't actually calculate with the normals. I noticed that the value of `screenNormalParam` integer was -1. I modified the vertex shader and added a `varying vec3 v_Normal` variable. I still don't use this variable to any calculation, since lightning doesn't matter for my application, but I just do a dummy assignment `v_Normal = a_Normal`:

```
uniform mat4 u_Model;
uniform mat4 u_MVMatrix;
uniform mat4 u_MVP;

attribute vec4 a_Position;
attribute vec3 a_Normal;
attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate;

varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;
varying vec3 v_Normal;

void main() {
   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate;
   v_Normal = a_Normal;

   gl_Position = u_MVP * a_Position;
}
```

`screenModelParam` (`u_Model`) and `screenModelViewParam` (`u_MVMatrix`) are still -1, but they are not used like `u_MVP`, and I don't call `GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray` on them. So far I don't see error messages now, but I don't understand why the dummy variable is needed, I guess I need to learn more about shaders.